# Unit Test Scanf

Tags: c++, visual-studio, unit-testing, testing

(Sorry for my english) I'm trying to make a unit test from a code of c++. In the next function (menu) there aren't any parameter into (). But into this funciton there are a scanf,that i would like testing but I haven't any idea how to make it.

Can I test scanf from Unit Test?

Thank you.

Code from function:

```
void principal::menu()
{
    int choice;
    system("cls");
    printf("\n--------MENU--------");
    printf("\n1 : Jugador X");
    printf("\n2 : Jugador O");
    printf("\n3 : Sortir");
    printf("\nTria el tipus de jugador: ");
    scanf_s("%d", &choice);
    turn = 1;
    switch (choice)
    {
    case 1:
        player = 1;
        comp = 0;
        player_first();
        break;
    case 2:
        player = 0;
        comp = 1;
        start_game();
        break;
    case 3:
        exit(1);
    default:
        menu();
    }
}
```

Code from test:

```
...
TEST_METHOD(menu){
   principal p; //this is the class --> not matter now

   //test code
}
```

If the code have a parameter I use the next code:

```
 ...
 TEST_METHOD(menu){
   principal p; //this is the class --> not matter now

   //test code
   Assert::AreEqual(result, parameter to enter);
}
```

Comment: Can you modify the existing code? Then you should split menu() into two functions, one that displays the menu and reads the input, the other that acts on the input, which would be easy to test then.

Comment: If not, and you are on *UX: Write the input parameters into text files, run the test program(s) with input redirection to the text file, then you can call menu() and test the result. You could also have multiple input values in the same file, then call menu() multiple times. (Of course there would be other, but more complicated solutions using fdup)

Answer (score 1):

If you use the C++ functions cin and cout you can redirect the buffer.

E.g.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <random>
#include <ctime>

int main()
{
    auto cout_buf = std::cout.rdbuf();
    std::stringbuf sb;
    std::cin.rdbuf(&sb);
    std::cout.rdbuf(&sb);

    std::mt19937 rand(time(nullptr));
    std::cout << (rand() % 100);

    int number;
    std::cin >> number;

    std::cout.rdbuf(cout_buf);
    std::cout << "The number was " << number << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `C/C++` is not a language.

Comment: Well yeah, it certainly isn't. I thought I saw that in the question but I was mistaken.

Comment: It does say C++ though, so I'm still in the clear :)

Comment: You did, It was in the question. I just edited it out. You can edit your answer to pick one of the languages.

Comment: Plus, to be a bit more on topic, `main()` returns `int` and `auto` requires C++11. Which in turn means that you can (and should) use `<random>` for a PRNG instead of `rand()`.

Comment: For a minimal example I don't think it matters, but sure - I'll update my answer.